# Embedded C , Renesas RL78, Transfer of data

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, rl78

I am trying to send 10-bit data from a Renesas MCU to another MCU. I am using 10-bit ADC, so the sensor data is in 10-bit format and then it is stored in a 2-byte variable. For example:

variable type:-

```
uint8_t data[2] = { 97, 65 }; 
uint8_t g_uart0_rx_buffer = 0U; 
uint8_t g_uart0_rx_error = 0U; 
volatile uint8_t * gp_uart0_tx_address; 
volatile uint16_t g_uart0_tx_count; 
uint16_t g_result_buffer = 0U; 
uint8_t check; 
uint8_t check_new = 8; 
int old_var = 0
```

```
uint8_t data[2] = {97 , 65}
```

It's working fine when I'm trying to send the whole two bytes; the code is given below:

```
R_ADC_Get_Result(&g_result_buffer);
old_var=g_result_buffer;
data[1] = old_var;
data[0] = (old_var >> 8);
g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send((uint8_t *) data, 2u);
```

And `R_UART0_Send()` is defined as:

```
MD_STATUS R_UART0_Send(uint8_t * const tx_buf, uint16_t tx_num)
{
    MD_STATUS status = MD_OK;

    if (tx_num < 1U)
    {
        status = MD_ARGERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        gp_uart0_tx_address = tx_buf;     //i.e volatile uint8_t * gp_uart0_tx_address;
        g_uart0_tx_count = tx_num;        //i.e volatile uint16_t  g_uart0_tx_count; 
        STMK0 = 1U;    /* disable INTST0 interrupt */
        TXD0 = *gp_uart0_tx_address;
        gp_uart0_tx_address++;
        g_uart0_tx_count--;
        STMK0 = 0U;    /* enable INTST0 interrupt */
    }

    return (status);
}
```

This part is working fine and I am getting data from UART and doing my further operation.

Now, I want to send minimum data from this MCU so I had implemented some encryption and tried to send only one byte as per my encryption. The idea behind encryption is:

I store the 10-bit data in `data[2]`, so eight bits are stored in `data[1]` and two bits are stored in `data[0]`. `data[0]` may be `0`,`1`,`2` or `3`. There is a condition on `data[0]`, that once it is `01` the MCU will transmit only one byte (i.e., `data[1]`) instead of sending the whole two bytes all the time. This continues until `data[0]` gets any other number (i.e., `0`,`2`, or `3`). This I do in the code below.

```
R_ADC_Get_Result(&g_result_buffer);
old_var=g_result_buffer;
data[1] = old_var;
data[0] = (old_var >> 8);
check = data[0];

if (check!=check_new) // check_new is declared globally with random variable
{
    if (check == 01)
    {
        //check_val = 'i';
        //g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send1((char) check_val, 1u);
        g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send((uint8_t *) data, 2u);
        check_new = check;
        //memset(data, 0, 2);
    }

    if (check == 02)
    {
        //check_val = 'j';
        //g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send1((char) check_val, 1u);
        g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send((uint8_t *) data, 2u);
        check_new = check;
        //memset(data, 0, 2);
    }

    if (check == 03)
    {
        //check_val = 'k';
        //g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send1((char) check_val, 1u);
        g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send((uint8_t *) data, 2u);
        check_new = check;
        //memset(data, 0, 2);
    }

    if (check == 00)
    {
        //check_val = 'l';
        //g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send1((char) check_val, 1u);
        g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send((uint8_t *) data, 2u);
        check_new = check;
        //memset(data, 0, 2);
    }

    //g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send((uint8_t *) data, 2u);
}
else
{
    g_uart0_tx_end = R_UART0_Send((uint8_t *) data+1, 1u);
    //memset(data, 0, 2);
}
```

Where `R_UART0_Send()` is defined with:

```
MD_STATUS R_UART0_Send(uint8_t * const tx_buf, uint16_t tx_num)
{
    MD_STATUS status = MD_OK;

    if (tx_num < 1U)
    {
        status = MD_ARGERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        if (tx_num == 1U){
        gp_uart0_tx_address = tx_buf;
        g_uart0_tx_count = tx_num;
        STMK0 = 1U;    /* disable INTST0 interrupt */
        TXD0 = *gp_uart0_tx_address;
        gp_uart0_tx_address++;
        g_uart0_tx_count--;
        STMK0 = 0U;    /* enable INTST0 interrupt */
        }
        else if (tx_num == 2U){
        gp_uart0_tx_address = tx_buf;
        g_uart0_tx_count = tx_num;
        STMK0 = 1U;    /* disable INTST0 interrupt */
        TXD0 = *gp_uart0_tx_address;
        gp_uart0_tx_address++;
        g_uart0_tx_count--;
        STMK0 = 0U;    /* enable INTST0 interrupt */
        }
    }

    return (status);
}
```

Initially the two-byte data is correct, and once it goes under the condition of sending one-byte data it's still correct. But when the condition changes and again it starts sending two-byte data, it starts sending `data[0]` incorrectly. Let me explain it with a example:

`data[0]` should be `0`,`1`,`2`, or `3`.

So the first two-byte data is `1,135`, so it stores the `data[0]` (i.e., `1`) in the variable `check_new` and checks `data[0]` for changes. Until then, it will only send `data[1]`.

Now initially it sends `1,135` and then it sends only `data[1]`, for example, `145`, `225`, `254`, `65`, `69`, `67`, etc.

Now if it gets some `data[0] = 2`, it should send `2,data[1]`, but at that time it starts sending `data[0] = 65` or `data[0] = 165`, or something else but not `0`,`1`,`2`, or `3`. Can you please help me that what I am doing wrong in this. Maybe I'm not incrementing the address or something else.

Comment: Impossible to answer since you didn't include the variable declarations. `(uint8_t *) data` suggests a type-related bug. Also what's the format of the data? Left aligned ADC? I take it data is Big Endian?

Comment: declaration of variable:- uint8_t  data[2] = { 97, 65 }; uint8_t  g_uart0_rx_buffer = 0U; uint8_t  g_uart0_rx_error = 0U; volatile uint8_t * gp_uart0_tx_address; volatile uint16_t  g_uart0_tx_count; uint16_t  g_result_buffer = 0U; uint8_t check; uint8_t check_new = 8; int old_var = 0. Now the type of data is Left aligned 10 bit ADC value. Yes, big endian.